# Python Regular Expression (\..+)?

Tags: python, regex

I am confused about the semantics of the following Python regular expression:

`r"/actors(\\..+)?"`

I looked through the Python documentation section on regular expressions, but couldn't make sense of this expression. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Well, look at one piece at a time. Do you know what the `\..+` piece matches?

Comment: see http://www.regex101.com/r/jX3tU9.

Comment: Thats the part that I find confusing. The rest makes sense to me.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Never seen that site before, very cool.

Comment: Is it `(\\..+)?` or `(\..+)?`?

Comment: @MitchVogel: your title and your question body mention two different regular expressions. Which one are you asking about?

Answer (score 6):

```
/        # literal /
actors   # literal actors
(        # starting a subpattern
\\       # (escaped) literal  \
.        # arbitrary character
.+       # 1 or more arbitrary characters
)?       # ends the subpattern and makes it optional
```

This would mean, it matches forward slash, 'actors', and then optionally backslash and 2 or more arbitrary characters.

I suppose there is a typo here. Either the string should not have been marked raw, or there is one backslash too much. In both cases there would be an escaped `.` instead of an escaped `\` followed by an arbitrary character. This in turn would matches files, called `actors` with an arbitrary or missing file extension.

So either `"/actors(\\..+)?"` or `r"/actors(\..+)?"`.

Comment: It's a raw string, so there is no need to escape the backslash. It's actually a backslash, followed by any character.

Comment: Oh, right. In that case it's probably a typo at one of the two places. I'll add that.

Answer (score 1):

```
\\..+
```

Here, `\\` is an escaped `\` character, so it does match that one exactly. Following is a `.` that can match any character, followed by another `.` that must be there at least once (or more often. So `..+` will match two characters *or more*. And `\\..+` will match any two characters or more, *prefixed by a backslash*.

```
(\\..+)?
```

That all is inside an optional capturing group means this all could be left out as well.

Note that the expression is probably wrong. It looks as if you are trying to match some kind of URL and want to match the file extension, introduced by a `.` character. However the `\\` inside a raw-enquoted string `r" "` will match the `\` character and will not escape the dot itself. So you probably want `r"/actors(\..+)?"` or `"/actors(\\..+)?"`.

Answer (score -1):

It means: string `/actors`, follow by an optional capture group, which contains a literal `.`, and then one or more of whatever the non-literal `.` is configured to match.

Comment: You are missing the fact that the pattern is a raw string. Your answer doesn't take that into account.

Comment: @BryanOakley Have a look at the title. It's ambiguous, I already commented that on the question. It also makes more sense to to not have a backslash in the URL (which I assume that's what it matches).